# Bash Script (awk-sed-grep) to check whether numbers in every next line are 1 more than previous line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file:

```
Time= 12:40:41, value = 1, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 2, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 3, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 4, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
...
...
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123456, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123457, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123458, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123459, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
```

I want to read this file using Cat | grep awk. 
And want to be able to run a command using combination of these to check if every number in the 'value' section increased by 1 in every next line. 
if this was not followed in any case I want to be able to see that point.

Till now: I am stuck at: 
$ Cat FileName | awk -F "= " '{print $4}'

Thanks

Comment: Show relevant sample data with **expected output**

Comment: So you are stuck with some marginally related code?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, $4 must be equal NR (awk like speaking). `$4 != NR { print }` could give some interesting output

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'next unless /value = ([0-9]+)/;
          print "$.: $_" if 1 + $value != $1;
          $value = $1' -- file.name
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- [next](http://p3rl.org/next) skips processing the line if there's no value to check.
- `$value` keeps the value from the previous line. If the captured value isn't equal to the old one plus one, the line number (`$.`) and the line (`$_`) are printed.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

Sample `input.txt`:

```
Time= 12:40:41, value = 1, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 2, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 3, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 5, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 6, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 7, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 9, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 10, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
```

---

```
awk 'v && ($5-1)!=v{ printf "value %d is not followed by %d\n",v,v+1 }{ v=$5+0 }' input.txt
```

- `v=$5+0` - capturing the current *value* (as a number)
- `v && ($5-1)!=v` - if the current *value* number `$5` is not *next* (increased by **1**) relatively to the previous one `v` (the equivalent condition is `v && $5+0!=v+1`)

---

The output:

```
value 3 is not followed by 4
value 7 is not followed by 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the input file `so.txt` has the following content:

```
Time= 12:40:41, value = 1, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 2, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 3, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 4, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 7, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 8, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 9, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 10, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
```

Here is a possible solution:

```
cat so.txt | awk {'print $5'} | tr -d , | awk '$1!=p+1{print "values from "p+1" to "$1-1" are missing"}{p=$1}'
```

This will output:

```
values from 5 to 6 are missing
```

If there are no gaps in the values field, the command will output nothing.

**How this works?**

The command can be broken as:

- `cat so.txt` will output the file content on stdout
- `awk {'print $5'}` will print the 5th column (which is the value field),
- `tr -d ,` to remove the comma separator

The final awk expression has:

- `$1` is the first column from current input line
- `p` is the previous value of the last line
- so `($1!=p+1)` is a condition : if `$1` is different than previous value +1, then :
- this part is executed : `{print "values from "p+1" to "$1-1" are missing"}` : print previous value +1 and the first columns +1 are missing
- `{p=$1}` is executed for each lines : `p` is assigned to the current 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '[ ,]' 'NR==1{p=$6;next} $6!=p+1{print "Mismatched line no:"NR} {p=$6}' file
```

**Input:**

```
Time= 12:40:41, value = 1, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 2, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 3, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 4, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123456, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123457, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123458, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
Time= 12:40:41, value = 123459, data=2, data2=4,timeEnter=12:34:34
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk -F '[ ,]' 'NR==1{p=$6;next} $6!=p+1{print "Mismatched line no:"NR} {p=$6}' file
Mismatched line no:5
```